# BaseActivity extends activity first but another activities get nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I want to create base activity for use every new activity, There is a fragment, which create 5 new intents. FourOne is first intent, this one works perfectly but others got nullpointerexception. How can i solve this problem?

BaseActivity

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
     private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
     private ListView mDrawerList;
     private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
     protected RelativeLayout _completeLayout, _activityLayout;
     // nav drawer title
     private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

      // used to store app title
     private CharSequence mTitle;

      private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
     private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

      @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.base_activity);
       //if (savedInstanceState == null) {
       //on first time display view for first nav item
      //displayView(0);
      // }
     }

      public void set(String[] menutitles,TypedArray menuIcons) {
      mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

       mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
       mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slider_list);

       navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

       // adding nav drawer items
      if(menuIcons==null){
      for(int i=0;i<menutitles.length;i++){
       navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(menutitles[i])); 
      }}else{
       for(int i=0;i<menutitles.length;i++){
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(menutitles[i],menuIcons.getResourceId(i, -1))); 
       }
      }

       mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

       // setting the nav drawer list adapter
      adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
        navDrawerItems);
      mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

       // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
      // getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer);

       mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, // nav menu toggle icon
        R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
             // accessibility
        R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
             // accessibility
      ) {
       public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
       }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
        // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
       }
      };
      mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

     }


      private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
       ListView.OnItemClickListener {
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {



       // display view for selected nav drawer item
       displayView(position);
      }
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      //getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

      if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
       if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
       } else {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
       }
      }

      return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }

     /***
      * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
      */
     @Override
     public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
      // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
      // menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
      return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
     }

     /**
      * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
      * */
     private void displayView(int position) {
      // update the main content by replacing fragments



         switch (position) {


         case 0:

               Intent intent = new Intent(this, FourOne.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();
               break;
              case 1:
               Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, FourTwo.class);
               startActivity(intent1);
               finish();
               break;
              case 2:
               Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, FourThree.class);
               startActivity(intent2);
               finish();
               break;
              case 3:
               Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, FourFour.class);
               startActivity(intent3);
               finish();
               break;
              case 4:
               Intent intent4 = new Intent(this, FourFive.class);
               startActivity(intent4);
               finish();
               break;     
              default:
                         break;
      }

      // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
      mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
      mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
      mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
     }

     @Override
     public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
      mTitle = title;
      getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
     }

     /**
      * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
      * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
      */

     @Override
     protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
      // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
      mDrawerToggle.syncState();
     }

     @Override
     public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
      // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
      mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
     }
    }
```

first  activity, this one works

```
    public class FourOne extends BaseActivity {


    private String[] menutitles;
    private TypedArray menuIcons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.four_one);



        menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titlestwo); // load titles from strings.xml

        menuIcons = getResources()
                        .obtainTypedArray(R.array.iconstwo);//load icons from strings.xml



        set(menutitles, menuIcons);

    }



}
```

second activity

```
    public class FourTwo extends BaseActivity {


    private String[] menutitles;
    private TypedArray menuIcons;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.four_two);



        menutitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titlestwo); // load titles from strings.xml

        menuIcons = getResources()
                        .obtainTypedArray(R.array.iconstwo);//load icons from strings.xml



        set(menutitles, menuIcons);

    }



}
```

logcat error

```
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sggsoftware.airsoftg/com.sggsoftware.airsoftg.FourTwo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.sggsoftware.airsoftg.BaseActivity.set(BaseActivity.java:65)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at com.sggsoftware.airsoftg.FourTwo.onCreate(FourTwo.java:28)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
07-15 07:36:17.647: E/AndroidRuntime(1703):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When onCreate is called in one of your Activities extending BaseActivity, you are calling super.onCreate, i.e. the onCreate of BaseActivity. Now the problem is that you are calling setContentView inside the BaseActivity's onCreate and after that again inside the actual Activity. This means your base_activity.xml is replaced by four_one.xml, four_two.xml, ... respectively. And that means, unless views such as R.id.drawer_layout also exist inside four_one.xml and so on, you won't be able to access those views. Hence the NullPointerException.

There are two solutions:

1. Drop the Activity-extending and instead make FourOne, FourTwo extend Fragment, put a container-layout inside base_activity.xml, and what else you have to do to use fragments.
2. Remove onCreate from BaseActivity and instead put all views from base_activity.xml you need in the different layouts four_one.xml, four_two.xml, ... respectively. Make use of include-tag, so you don't have to repeat XML-code.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i forget modify 2,3,4,5 xml files, after change them activities work.